# ListView with cateogarized disabled items

Tags: android, listview, categories

I want to create a ListView with categorized list items.

Same as in the case of Contacts application:

I categorizes according to the Initials.

I would have to create my own adapter thats for sure with some logic.

But can anyone tell me any best practice or a small tutorial to get me started. I have started to learn the default contacts application.

Heres what I want:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are definitely heading in the right direction with the Adapter class. I can't think of any tutorial out there but if you study Android's [HeaderListViewAdapter](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/HeaderViewListAdapter.java;h=e2a269ea13efb74a533a32ecdbf610a17adbca5a;hb=refs/heads/master) source that might help.

To start you will probably want to wrap the Adapter that contains the data in a new custom Adapter class, perhaps you will call it `CategorizedAdapter`. Your `CategorizedAdapter` will provide additional category items that the wrapped adapter does not have, it will modify the id numbers to make room for these new items. These category items would have a different type as returned by the [getItemViewType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) method and thus be rendered differently.

Good luck.

Comment: Ok :) Thanks buddy. This can surely get me started. I will mark your answer accepted when I'll work this out. Stay with me!

Comment: Can you give me some sample :(

Comment: Your best sample is the HeadListViewAdapter. I would copy that file and rename it to CategorizedAdapter.java and then use it as a guide. If you are really stuck you can try writing a class that inserts a single item into the middle of the list as an exercise. I would provide the code, but even inserting an item in the middle of a list requires a non-trivial amount of work!

Comment: Here is a link to another question that has useful answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376871/android-list-view-with-separators