# Android List view with separators

Tags: android

I want to create a listview with separators like in the default contacts application. My application needs that the list be sorted and the items be separated by separators(like the alphabetical sorting in contacts application). Being able to scroll using the separator titles would be an added advantage. Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this open source project, it gives you headers and they are sticky too:

https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

Answer (score 1):

Go to your **android-sdk\samples** folder. There's a lot of examples with source. Try **api demos -> Views -> Lists**. This samples are everything you need and even more. Moreover [HERE](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/index.html) are official examples in `Lists` section.

Comment: I checked that but it did not have any such example.

Comment: Right, you haven't installed "Samples for SDK API xxx". [HERE](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/get.html) is explained how to do it.

Comment: I have installed it buddy but it has no example for a separated list view.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the divider and their width via **xml** or **code** :

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android:dividerHeight
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android:divider
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setDivider(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setDividerHeight(int)

For using the default divider , use "`?android:attr/listDivider`" for the "`divider`" attribute.

Also, in order to be able to do the scrolling in a different, faster way, use [fastScrollEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3afastScrollEnabled) .

Answer (score 0):

Try to look this open source project.

https://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/