# ListView with extra view between elements

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I use ListView with CursorAdapter. It was greate. But customer ordered additional information in list between view:

[image]

How can I provide this?

UPDATE:

```
public class OutlaysCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private static int NUMBER;
private static int ID;
private static int NOTE;
private static int TYPE;
private static int SUM;
private static int DATE;
private static int ODOMETER;
private static int UNREAD;
private static int FUTURE;
private static int INPUT_TYPE;


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

    return super.getView(arg0, arg1, arg2);
}


@Override
public View newView(Context paramContext, Cursor cursor,    ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {

    if(cursor.getInt(TYPE)==0){
        return new OutlaySeparatorView(paramContext);
    } else {
        return new OutlayItemView(paramContext);
    }

}


@Override
public void bindView(View paramView, Context paramContext,  Cursor cursor) {

    long date = cursor.getLong(DATE);
    int type = cursor.getInt(TYPE);
    float sum = cursor.getFloat(SUM);

    if(type == 0){

        ((OutlaySeparatorView)paramView).setData(date, (int)sum);

    } else {

        OutlayItemView view = (OutlayItemView) paramView;

        Outlay outlay = new Outlay();
        outlay.setNumber(cursor.getInt(NUMBER));
        outlay.setId(cursor.getInt(ID));
        outlay.setDate(date);
        outlay.setNote(cursor.getString(NOTE));
        outlay.setType(type);
        outlay.setSum(sum);
        outlay.setOdometer(cursor.getInt(ODOMETER));
        outlay.setUnread(cursor.getInt(UNREAD) == 1);
        outlay.setFuture(cursor.getInt(FUTURE) == 1);
        outlay.setInputType(cursor.getString(INPUT_TYPE));

        view.setOutlay(outlay);

    }

}

public OutlaysCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {

    super(context, c, autoRequery);
    initialize(context, c);

}

public OutlaysCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {

    super(context, c, flags);
    initialize(context, c);
}

private void initialize(Context context, Cursor c){

    NUMBER = c.getColumnIndex("countNum");
    ID = c.getColumnIndex("id");
    SUM = c.getColumnIndex("sum");
    NOTE = c.getColumnIndex("note");
    TYPE = c.getColumnIndex("type");
    DATE = c.getColumnIndex("date");
    ODOMETER = c.getColumnIndex("odometer");
    UNREAD = c.getColumnIndex("unread");
    FUTURE = c.getColumnIndex("future");
    INPUT_TYPE = c.getColumnIndex("input_type");

}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {

    return 2;
}


}
```

This code works fine, for first showing, but when I add new row and call getCursor().requery() this code crashed with ClassCastException.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376871/android-list-view-with-separators .check this

Answer (score 1):

you have to implement your custom Adapter and override `getItemViewType` and `getViewTypeCount`. `getViewTypeCount` has to return 2 (one View for a normal row, one for the Separtor). `getItemViewType` should return an int that will indetify the type of  the View. The `getView` will receive the null convertView twice, one for the normal row, one for the separator

Comment: Can't understand. How can I get itemViewType by position in getItemViewType? From cursor? Do you have any example? I have updated question.

Comment: that's up to you. How do you understand when it's time to show the separator?

Comment: It's ok. I updated question - added code. bindView work fine, but I can't understand, how shoul work getItemViewType  and getView together

Answer (score 0):

Create your own adapter which would check if the row to display is "data" and get it from underlying CursorAdapter, or "separator" and provide a different view instead.